# jQuery(window).scrollTop() issue in Firefox?

Tags: jquery, firefox

I have the following code that I use to display a hidden footer when you scroll down past a certain point on the page.

```
jQuery(document).scroll(function(){
    if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= jQuery('.foot').offset().top + jQuery('.foot').height() - window.innerHeight) {
        // Add class here
    } else {
        // Remove class here
});
```

This works fine in Chrome and IE. But doesn't work in Firefox. I've narrowed the problem down to jQuery(window).scrollTop(). I've created this test http://jsfiddle.net/captainmorgan/cVsRE/1/
Open in Chrome and scroll down with the mouse wheel. I get 100. When I do the same thing in Firefox I get 114, but Firefox continues to display multiple messageboxes and the number keeps decreasing.
Does anyone know why Firefox does this?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(event) {
    var NextScroll = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
    if(NextScroll > (jQuery('.foot').offset().top + jQuery('.foot').height() - window.innerHeight)) {
         //action
    }

});
```

Comment: That still doesn't work in Firefox as NextScroll will start off with (for example 114, but it will keep decreasing in value until it reaches 0, as which point, the first part of the if statement is never reached.

Comment: I use that code in http://www.superkul.no/ mobile device. I think it work in Firefox

Comment: If you add an alert to NextScroll, you will see that Firefox displays multiple message boxes which results in NextScroll finishing with a 0 value all the time.

Comment: When debug, you shouldn't use alert. You should use console.log(NextScroll).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It still doesn't change the fact that there is either an issue with Firefox, or I need to code differently.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. I was hoping someone could explain why Firefox has this looping issue with scrollTop(), then I'd be able to figure the rest out